# Append lines after match

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to print eg 5 lines after a match? Would like to use similar to below:

```
var error="1234";

fs.readFileSync('errors.txt').toString().split('\n').forEach(function(line){
    var idx = line.match(error);
    if (idx !== null) {
        fs.appendFileSync(result.txt, line + "\n");
    }
});
```

Which gives me only matching line.
My goal is to append matching and 5 succeeding lines or even better all lines between 2 matches.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a variable to track whether we're appending or not (defined outside of the forEach loop), and then modify and test the variable as needed. Something like:

```
var appending = 0  
if (idx !== null || appending > 0) {  
  fs.appendFileSync(...)  
  appending = (appending === 0) ? 5 : appending - 1  
}
```

Comment: Thank you, will give it a try

Comment: Works as a charm, would never figure this out on my own. Thank you.